# how to get the following checkbox to show outiside the submit button

Tags: android

I have the following Edittext, which is set to hidden but if the user check the option called other, it will appear. I thought that the following code should work? I can get it to work inside my submit button but not outside of it.... Can you do this outside the submit button?

```
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message6"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:hint="Other instrument not listed above:"

            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />


if(other.isChecked()) {

            message6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this method-->

```
CheckBox check= (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkboxid);
check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
          message6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     
    }
    else 
      message6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 

  }
});
```

OR

```
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
             message6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }else {
               message6.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think in the else you meant `message6.setVisibility(View.GONE)` but +1 otherwise

Comment: thanks.. I didn't know that you also can set the setOnClickListener to a checkbox... thought you needed a button for that..

Comment: how do you uncheck checkboxes?

Comment: i got it... I have used... setChecked(false)